# How to use ArrayList instead

Tags: java, arraylist, vector

Would an ArrayList be better to use than Vector?
I've tried changing the code to ArrayList for all Vector values but I get an error on the return statement at the end of my myTableModel method

Edit: for clarification I have heard and read a few people mention that the use of vectors is poor in 2017 (and that ArrayList is preferred). Still really new to java so my thinking clearly isn't where it should be (as clearly pointed out by other users) :)

```
public static DefaultTableModel myTableModel(){
        csvData = new Vector();
    readInData();
    String header = csvData.get(0);
    String[] columns = header.split("[,]");
    Vector<String> colNames = new Vector<>();
    int columnCount = columns.length;
    for (int column = 0; column < columnCount; column++) {
        colNames.add(columns[column]);
    }
    Vector<Vector<Object>> data = new Vector<>();


    for(int j = 1 ; j < csvData.size() ; j++){
        String row = csvData.get(j);
        String[] elements = row.split("[,]");
            Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<>();
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; columnIndex++) {
            vector.add(elements[columnIndex]);
        }
        data.add(vector);
    }

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames);
```

Comment: To adress your first question: ["Vector is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use ArrayList in place of Vector."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Comment: `new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames);` this requires a vector. does not work with arrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting things wrong: you don't select this or that class because you heard somebody say this or that. You decide to select a certain class  because it makes **sense**. Because it helps you to get your job done.

Example: when you turn to the javadoc for that [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) you will find: that class does **not** provide a constructor that accepts an ArrayList! Thus: no need to change your code; when the **goal** of your code is to create such a DefaultTableModel object!

So, as the other answer points out correctly: sometimes the answer is not to use a class with "more" features; but to look closely at your problem; and even replace dynamic vectors with fixed-size arrays. Because they do the job!

But when stepping back; and talking in general: then yes, using ArrayList instead of Vector has a number of advantages; and in 2017; when you write new code; your "default" would be to use List/ArrayList instead of Vector.

Comment: Thank you, this comment really hits home with where my mind set should be, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Be simple!

```java
public static DefaultTableModel myTableModel() {
    String[] csv = readInData();
    String[] columnNames = csv[0].split(",");
    Object[][] data = new Object[csv.length - 1][];

    for (int row = 1; row < data.length; row++)
        data[row] = csv[row].split(",");

    return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
}
```

Comment: You might want to talk just a little bit about what your code is doing. Yes, it is simple code, but still: code only answers are no ideal!